# Why cannot pass print function to dir() in python?

Tags: python

Is print a built-in function? If it is, why I cannot run `dir(print)`? `dir` is a built-in function and `dir(dir)` works well. So it looks very strange to me that `dir(print)` could not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In python 2 print is a statement and not a function and you can't put a statement as a function argument, in the other hand in python3 [print is a function](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) so you can do `dir(print)`.

Comment: In Python 2.6 and later you can do `from __future__ import print_function` first to get the same behavior.